# Dired doesn't open non-text files with external applications in a Tramp directory listing

Tags: dired, tramp

In Dired I'm in a Tramp directory opened with `/sftp:...` (so using the `gvfs` backend).

If I use `&` to open a non-text file with a local external application (ex. `evince` for PDF) it doesn't do anything (no errors).

It works in a local directory (and it works when I open a text file in the same remote directory).

Answer (score 2):

`sftp` is implemented in Tramp by GVFS, so it doesn't support remote processes. You must use a Tramp method like `ssh` or `scp`.

Comment: but i don't want to use a remote application; i want it to use a local application; and using gvfs, so a local mounted disk, it should behave as if it were a local directory... strange

Comment: Tramp doesn't provide the files as mounted files. If you want to use them this way, use their mount file names, something like `/run/user/<NNN>/gvfs/...`